# Написать post запрос, который возвращает короткий url страницы

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, ruby

Всем доброго времени суток! Начинаю изучать rails с помощью туториала (http://rusrails.ru/getting-started-with-rails) и столкнулся вот с какой проблемой: не понимаю как реализовать post запрос. Если я правильно понял, то get-запрос реализуется через routes.rb, но про post не нашел ничего. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где нарыть информацию про реализацию post запросов в rails ;(

Comment: А на каком этапе возникли проблемы? Если вы в роутах укажете ресурсный роут, например `resources :articles`, то для `create` роут автоматически сгенерится с глаголом `POST` - http://rusrails.ru/getting-started-with-rails#resursnyy-routing